# Translucency in uinavigationbar works in iPhone 5 but not in 4s

Tags: iphone, uinavigationbar, ios7

we have an ios7 app which runs fine on the iphone 5 so far. We have an uinavigationcontroller which uses a uinavigationbar. We set the bar to be translucent like so:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
```

However this does not seem to work on the iphone 4s. The bar is there but theres no translucency. I added two screenshots below to demonstrate.

The first picture is on the 5 and the second one on the 4s. Any ideas?

[image: the correct display with translucency on the iphone 5]

[image: without translucency on the 4s]

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure it's a 4S and not a 4? (they both look the same).

The 4 doesn't support translucency but the 4S should. Check if it has Siri, hold down the home button for 5 seconds, if it has Siri then it's definitely a 4S.

Comment: This sounds right to me (I've verified this on my iPhone4, but can't test on a 4S), and good suggestion for differentiating the two devices.

Comment: Yes it really is a 4S. We double checked to make sure. We also asked Siri for a solution but she didn't seem to understand :) Transparency and blur also works in other apps on the phone.

Comment: That's very strange. Can you start a new project with the master detail template and install it straight onto the phone without changing any code? If translucency works on this then I think there's something else in your app affecting it.